# Grid with empty rows in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I want to have a excel like grid with empty rows(n-number of rows). The GridView is bound to a collection of m number of model objects.
If user enters a new data into empty row the new model object must be added to the bound collection.

Comment: So create some empty model objects in your collection. What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the standard `DataGrid`? It does exactly what you're describing. Or do you want to know how to use it?

Comment: If you want to allow a user to enter rows of data with blank rows between them (like a spreadsheet), then your best bet is probably many empty model objects, as GazTheDestroyer said.

Comment: If the user enters data in to row 10 before any other row, does the model need to introduce 9 blank objects to preserve the gap or do you end up with 1 object in the model that's given a RowNumber property, this changes how I would suggest doing it so I'll ask before providing code.

Comment: Andy I dont want model to have any null or empty row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone is suggesting that you introduce empty model objects into your collection to create your empty rows, but your last comment said you don't want any empty rows in your model. This is exactly what having a `ViewModel` will allow you do.  Your `ViewModel` contains your display collection that can have the additional empty model objects but still not persist them back to your `Model` layer.  The key is that your `ViewModel` collection is not the same as your `Model` collection.

If you ever need to load this data back up into this screen and keep everything where it was, then you will need to persist a row number with each model object and then you can insert empty model objects where needed.

Comment: I had done the same way A long time ago but never got a chance to comeback to this question and post the answer. Anyways thanks